# How can I set a different Docker image location under Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker, opensuse

I'm using openSUSE Tumbleweed, fully updated. My current system setup has two partitions, one for `/` formatted with "btrfs", and another for `/home`, using "ext4".

I'd like to set the Docker image location in a position different than the default place in `/var/lib/docker/`, maybe in  `/home/docker-data/`.

How can I do that? I found some guides, but I don't know if these are relevant to openSUSE or up to date with the latest Docker versions.

I've read that I should also set a different Storage Driver (currently it is set as `btrfs`, but the partition where I want to store the images is formatted with `ext4`), how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory

> With recent versions of Docker, you would set the value of the graph parameter to your custom path, in /etc/docker/daemon.json (according to https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file).
>
> With older versions, you can change Docker's storage base directory (where container and images go) using the -goption when starting the Docker daemon. (check docker --help). You can have this setting applied automatically when Docker starts by adding it to /etc/default/docker

Alternatively:

You can use the `--graph` or `--data-root` option in the service file where `ExecStart` is defined after dockerd, e.g. `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --graph="/mnt"`

With your second question, if you're referring to the Docker storage driver, [you can define it using the daemon.json file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#check-and-set-your-current-storage-driver)